# How to scale text search on ElasticSearch with very large indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to optimize **text search** over a very large set of documents. As a test dataset, I am using the Enron email dataset ~ 3GB, but an actual dataset may be 100GB+. My structure is basically  **GET /enron/email/1**.

Some Engineering Constraints:

- Search response times < 100 ms
- Reduce duplication of entire dataset as much as possible
- The documents can be assumed to be immutable.
- Text may be searched in a wide range of ways. Here are some examples:

  - Find all emails that mention the word "california power"
  - Find all emails that contain "califoria" and fuzzy match that to california
  - Find all emails that contain "easy money AND NOT hard work"
  - Find all emails that contain "stealing OR blackmail"

It seems from my reading that I should prefer to have shards over replicas if I don't want to duplicate the data. I'd appreciate any insight you can give me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*To scale a text search on large indices*

Horizontal scaling is important feature in Elasticsearch (consider using multiple nodes to experience the power of clustering)

In the case of sharding, we don't have any magic number to mention that this number of shards will provide better performance (shards needs to be splitted based on our data size). so we have to made few experiments to decide our suitable shards

Creating an effective mapping will help reach out the data easily. for example if we are going to store a email in a document means we can split out the data into different fields like sender, recipient list, subject, body of mail. We can decide which analyzer we need to use while creating the mapping

Es Heap size, by default Elasticsearch will have 1 GB heap size. we have to customize the heap size based on our available RAM in machines (we have official documentations for this setting).

We can call replica as the copy of original data other than calling as duplicate data. Replica shards will be UP automatically when our primary shards went down (and again enabling replica is based our need of data availability)